# Database performance concern

Tags: database, performance, connection

So, I've got a game server with an accompanying database that works just like any game database, and does it well too. The thing is I'm now thinking of adding a webpage with some stats to go with the game; for example some way to see your character from outside the game; see your stats, standing etc.

My concern is if having this webpage connect to the same database, would it noticably slow down the game server? Or, since it's a different connection, can they work efficiently at the same time? The webpage will just be for displaying information, so it will simply use SELECTs on the data created by the game server.

Is this, performance wise, an acceptable way of doing it, or should I look into stuff such as keeping a seperate database for the webpage that only on low-population hours fetches data from the game server's database, and thusly is kept slightly out of synch, but with less strain on the server latency?

P.S. I'm using MySql 5.5

Comment: this is quite open ended really. There are many, many variables that will play a part in this. i.e. what is the structure of your database, what are you selecting, how often, what indexes do you have, etc., etc. I can't see how anyone could answer this question really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't know until you try it. My advice would be to have your game server and stats page connect to the same database and see what happens. Databases like MySQL are designed to handle lots of connections at once (that is why it is popular with websites - many incoming requests at once), but if you then find that it is adversely affecting your game server you can consider a more optimal solution.

In general, don't over-optimize. Go with a solution that works first, then see if it is worth improving.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go ahead and try it :).